# How to store variable from new instance in Java

Tags: java, oop, instance

I'm not sure if that is the correct title to use but...
I have been given a program with test cases eg:

```
private void Test(){
  CompareString string1 = new CompareString("String here");
  CompareString string2 = new CompareString("String there");
  assertEquals(expected, string1.compareTo(string2));
}
```

(I cannot change the Tests)

And a class

```
public class CompareString{

  CompareString(String stringIn){  //your code here  }

public boolean compareTo(CompareString aString){
   //your code here
   return true;
  }
}
```

How do I get each string stored separately in order to do the comparison (and further work that is not described here)

With the test calling a 'new' instance, any variables I try to store and create are reset.
I tried to use the `this.stringVariable = stringIn`  but this obviously will only store the last string instance ("string there" in this case). How can i store the strings separately?

Comment: Why don't you have any field in `CompareString` class? I clearly see that your constructor is taking one argument `String stringIn`.

Comment: I don't quite get what you mean by that whole "storing seperatly" thing. In the tests you are creating 2 seperate pbjects "string1" and "string2" and in the compareTo method you are comparing 2 objects. Those 2 are already seperate objects that do not share any data.

Comment: This is a challenge I have been given, so I am meant to add in the constructors if needed. Storing them separately was just the idea I thought I had to do so I could access them to use in different functions etc, how else am I meant to access the two separate strings that are passed in?

Comment: @gettingthereslowly Your problem seems to be understanding what Objects are. `CompareString string1 = new CompareString("String here");` is creating an object and `CompareString string2 = new CompareString("String there");` is creating another object. The fact that they are of the same class does not mean they have to share any data and in fact they currently don't. You just need to save the string inside the object as a field/member variable and then use those 2 objects created..

Comment: You are meant to store the `stringIn` in a global variable within the `CompareString` class.  You then compare that global variable with the `aString` parameter in your `compareTo()` method.

Comment: if the last instance not related to the current object you can make a static variable that can store last instance

Comment: There is no such thing as a "global variable" in Java. What you are talking about is called a field, and it is only available within the object's scope, not globally throughout the whole program.

Comment: Thank you everyone, I have managed to get a working version using the static variables, `private static String string1`, `private static String string2` . I'm not sure if this is best practice but it seems to be working for now!

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that you have a test which you cannot modify and you have a class used by this test which is partially implemented. You are asking about the implementation by asking "How do I get each string stored separately...". *(Hint: this is called encapsulation, but read further)*

I would like to point out a good resource for you [The Java™ Tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/)

There you will learn about [objects](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/object.html), data encapsulation, and [constructors](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/index.html).

You task is to implement a constructor and method. After you learn the essentials I outlined you will be able to solve the problem. We can help you writing the coded but you would not learn how to do it yourself.